# Declaration without state

Tags: c#, button, triggers, declaration

Hello I have simple code and would like to have one button control of label:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    bool T=true;

    if (T)
    {
        label1.Text = "GOOD";
        T=false;
    }
    else if(!T){
        label1.Text = "BAD";
        T=true;
    }
}
```

The problem is that every time I press button its declares as true and every time is true condition. I cannot declare it like this

```
bool T;
```

because getting an error:

> CS0165    Use of unassigned local variable 'T'    WindowsFormsApp1

How I can declare it once?

Comment: Use a Field instead of a local variable. Assign a default value that fits (i.e., decide if you want it be `true` or `false` by default). Then you probably want `label1.Text = T ? "GOOD" : "BAD"; T = !T`

Comment: Declare it outside of the method and give it a starting value like you did inside the method

Comment: I don´t see what you actually want to **achieve**. At the beginning `T` will allways be true, making the first condition **allways** fit. This changes `T` to become `false`, making the second condition fit (I suppose you want `iì f`, not `else if`). So it seems to me both branches should allways execute, making the conditon meaningless?

Comment: This code seems to suggest that you need to better understand the concept of variable scope.

Comment: Why my post is downvoted? im just try to learn ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to toggle between some cklicked-state and unclicked state, you need a member within your **class**, not variable that exists only within the **method**:

```
class MyClass
{
    bool foo;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        if (this.foo)
        {
            label1.Text = "GOOD";
            this.foo=false;
        }
        else
        {
            label1.Text = "BAD";
            this.foo = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Also notice I´ve omited the `else if` because a bool can have only two states: `true` or `false`. There´s no way for a third condition. So everything that does **not** match the first condition will automatically match the second, you don´t need to test (again) for the bool-value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to switch the `label1.Text` from `GOOD` to `BAD` you can try a simple turnary operator:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    label1.Text = string.Equals("GOOD", label1.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
      ? "BAD"
      : "GOOD";
}
```

If you want a more elaborated solution, let's *extract a property*, e.g.:

```
public bool IsGood {
  get {
    // Simplest implementation; often adding a backing field is a good idea
    return label1.Text = string
      .Equals("GOOD", label1.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
  }
  set {
    label1.Text = value ? "GOOD" : "BAD";
  }
}
```

then on click event

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   IsGood = !IsGood; 
 }
```